# Hardware Calculate for Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, hardware

How can i calculate recommended hardware for a sql server ?
How can i implement hardware plan for sql server ?

**After Edit:**

My Application is Designed By Silverlight.
I 30 table in my database and i store picture or pdf files in some tables.
I have 1000 user.
I have 500 concurrent sessions.

Comment: This is hopelessly vague.  Do some research based on what your needs will be.  We can't give you any semblance of help without any semblance of requirements.  What kind of application is it?  What kind of data will you be storing?  How many users will you have?  How many concurrent sessions will you be running?  Is it OLTP?  Is it data warehousing?  Throw us a bone.

Comment: Once you've calculated it (or estimated it), you "implement hardware plan" via the process of buying the hardware. What are you actually asking?

Comment: @hosseinsinohe, do no moderator alert requesting for poorly written questions to be reopened simply because you've actually added a tiny and insignificant amount of 'detail'.

Answer (score 3):

A two links you may find helpful:

Hardware Sizing Microsoft SQL Server
http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Tips0012.htm

Server Sizing Tool
http://www.sizinglounge.com/

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any other information

1. Plenty of fast RAID 10 disks. Or SSDs
2. 64 bit
3. As much RAM as you can afford. And add some more

Note: if it runs slow, your design and code is probably wrong